# Drupal 7 Core Blog Module: why can't I update this page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm new to Drupal and having an issue with the `Blog` feature. I need a blog on my site and the core module `Blog` seemed sufficient. I enabled it and added few `Blog` nodes. But on every page there is a banner that pops up at the bottom of page to customize the page, but for some reason I don't have that on the page generated by the blog module.

My problem is I'm trying to add a block for the list of categories (Taxonomy) for `blog posts`. I added the taxonomy group and associated terms. Now there's a block I can drag onto the page (through Block's admin-page), but I can't do it through the admin side. I configured the `block` to be shown on blog pages by limiting the Content Type to `Blog` but still that particular block is not being shown on the /blog page.

Any help/guidance appreciated.

Comment: have you checked "Display on specific pages" radio button below block configure page. If yes then place "/blog" in the text area below the radio button.

Comment: @swinkle - please elaborate more about the sentence - `But on every page there is a banner that pops up at the bottom of page to customize the page`.

Comment: @PralhadNarsinhSonar it's just the "customize page" banner that Drupal displays on every page, where you can add blocks, edit the layout, etc.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki I have tried that, yes. I put blog and /blog under there, and regardless it still does not display.

Comment: @swinkel check your block view alter hook or your block view hooks for any unset of block variable.

Comment: @swinkel Blocks can be a huge pain sometimes, especially when the situation is a very straightforward one. A block was added so it should show up in certain places. Drupal cache needs to be cleared for these kinds of changes to reflect. https://www.drupal.org/documentation/clearing-rebuilding-cache